# Autovacuum struggles with 2000 tables reaching autovacuum_freeze_max_age simultaneously

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum

My goal is to keep `autovacuum` very responsive to current events, mainly so that tables are always properly `analyzed`. At the same time, I have huge batches of ~2000 tables that need wraparound-prevention vacuum. These batches delay `autovacuum analyze`.

What is the best way to solve this (while keeping the app the same)? My current plan is to write a script that does the wraparound-prevention so that autovacuum is free for current events (updates, deletes) so for `vacuum` and `analyze`. Is there a better way? Only by changing autovacuum settings maybe? I could just hardcode all `analzye` so that I do not rely on `autovacuum` for correct statistics, but that does not see the best way?

I have this problem as my app does the following:

- Day 1: Insert data into 2000 empty tables (mainly partitions of tables) using many transaction IDs
- Day 1, but a few minutes later: Read data from these 2000 tables (so statistics need to be correct, otherwise the execution plans are incorect, so analyze must have run in between)
- Day 2: Insert data into 2000 new empty tables, again using many transaction IDs (this will make that the 2000 tables filled the day before need wraparound-protection vacuum)
- Day 2, a few minutes later: Read data from the 2000 new tables - **Now the problem happens as `autovacuum` is busy with wraparound-protection of the old 2000 tables and statistics on the new 2000 tables are incorrect**

Comment: What is your setting for autovacuum_freeze_max_age? SHOW autovacuum_freeze_max_age; And why do you have to use so many tables and transactions per day? One batch of a million records could be done in a single transaction.

Comment: hi. `autovacuum_freeze_max_age` is at 200mio. "day 1" and "day 2" is only for illustration purposes, sorry. there is more time in between. But yes, there are 150 mio transactions in between (`vacuum_freeze_min_age ` is 50mio).

Comment: Change this setting to a (much) higher setting and schedule vacuum jobs yourself during quiet hours. Changing your scripts could reduce the need for vacuum, when you do more work in a single transaction. 10 inserts wrapped in a single transaction, is 10 times cheaper then 10 single inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could just hardcode all analzye so that I do not rely on autovacuum for correct statistics, but that does not see the best way?

Normally I would agree that that is not the best way.  But since you need the ANALYZE to happen within the span of "a few minutes later", I would say it probably *is* the best way.

That doesn't mean you can't also issue preemptive 'vacuum freeze' at some convenient time, like over night, or over a weekend.

Are you really using 200,000,000 transactions every day?